# Adding extra column which contains x values, repeat the x values for whole column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have list

```
a = ["0-3","4-7","8-11","12-15","16-19","20-23"]
```

I want to repeat all elements in the list for a new column in a dataframe which has 1000 rows. How to do that in pandas?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to post a good reproducible question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDITED:

Please refer to my comment, but if I understand you correctly you need:

```
import pandas as pd

a_list = (["0-3","4-7","8-11","12-15","16-19","20-23"]*167)[:1000]

series = pd.Series(a_list)

print(series)

0        0-3
1        4-7
2       8-11
3      12-15
4      16-19
       ...
995    20-23
996      0-3
997      4-7
998     8-11
999    12-15
Length: 1000, dtype: object
```

Comment: `pd.Series` also has a [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) func

Comment: Thanks. here each element is repeating 167 times then next element. I want to all 6 the elements from 0 to 5th row then repeat whole list. Is this possible?